# Add package dependencies with Mono-d or Visual-d

Tags: dependencies, d

With dub I can do this in the dub.json file:

```
{
    "name": "myproject",
    "description": "A little web service of mine.",
    "authors": ["Peter Parker"],
    "homepage": "http://myproject.com",
    "license": "GPL-2.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "vibe-d": ">=0.7.11"
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent thing in Mono-D or Visual-D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used VisualD, but in Mono-D you can just create a project from a dub package descriptor - just create your package.json and select it in the open project dialogue. Adding stuff to the package.json later should cause the project to reload automatically.