# How to set up an external dependency with DUB in mono-D?

Tags: monodevelop, d

I'd like to try developing D in IDE. I'd like to use a [`scriptlike` external library](http://code.dlang.org/packages/scriptlike) (available via dub). But whatever I do, it never make it work; Mono-D complains about the module `scriptlike` that it "cannot be read".

When I try to open the file "dub.json" in Mono-D with the following contents:

```
"dependencies": {
    "scriptlike": "~>0.9.4"
}
```

I get the error:

> ```
> Exception while reading dub package /home/Adama-docs/Adam/linux/tmp/test-d/test-scriptlike/dub.json.
> ```
>
> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: :.
>   Path '', line 1, position 14.
>
> ```
> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: :. Path '', line 1, position 14.
> ```

So the solution in [Add package dependencies with Mono-d or Visual-d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572547/add-package-dependencies-with-mono-d-or-visual-d) doesn't really work for me.

Even if Mono-D would open the `dub.json`, it will still be only partial solution: what to do if I have an already existing project in Mono-D that is not based on any `.json` file, and want to add an external library to it?

I guess I miss something fairly basic, but unfortunately I cannot google out anything constructive.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, `dmd --version`: DMD64 D Compiler v2.068.2, MonoDevelop version 5.9.6 and D language bindings version 2.13.5.

Comment: Does it work from the command-line?

Comment: @DejanLekic It does if I prepend the file with the shebang: `#!/usr/bin/rdmd --shebang -I~/.dub/packages/scriptlike-0.9.4/src/` and execute it directly.

Comment: The error is saying that your `dub.json` file is formatted incorrectly. Please show the complete `dub.json` file.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski: I was talking about dub - does it work with that JSON above from command-line? Maybe simply your JSON is not valid...

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Ok; you are right. The correct dub.json should be enclosed in curly braces. When I open it, I have no files included in the project; I know I can add these into the dub.json if I learn the correct format. The question remains: is it possible to add external dependency into D project without making/editing the dub.json manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mono-d does not support adding dependencies directly, if u use dub editing the dub.json is the only way right now. You could however create an issue for this on mono-d's github

Answer (score 0):

For now, until MonoD starts supporting external dependencies with its GUI, one needs to generate the dub.json manually.

#### The minimalistic example of `dub.json`

First, in the project's main directory make sure the main source file is called `app.d` or `main.d` and it exists in a directory `src` or `source`.

Then create in the main project's directory a file `dub.json` with the contents similar to this one:

```
{
    "name" : "hello-world",
    "description" : "Hello World - A minimal working example with external dependencies.",
    "dependencies" : {"scriptlike": ">=0.9.4"
    }
}
```

I guess the "description" field is not mandatory, but it shouldn't hurt putting it there.

After that open this file with MonoD using File->Open... dialog.